# How to toggle visibility of thumbnail strip in Fancybox 4?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

From the guide

> You can check current state of Thumbnail plugin and toggle visibility
> of thumbnail strip using API:
>
> Fancybox.getInstance().plugins.Thumbs.state;

> Fancybox.getInstance().plugins.Thumbs.toggle();

and since it shows thumbnail automatic when opened, I use it this way to disable visibility of thumbnail strip

```
        ...
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                Fancybox.getInstance().plugins.Thumbs.toggle();
            
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it does not work, so how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code snippet:

`Fancybox.getInstance()`

allows you to get reference to the top most active instance.
This means that your code will not work just because you have not started Fancybox.

To toggle visibility at the start, simply use `autoStart` option like this:

```js
Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox]", {
  Thumbs: {
    autoStart: false,
  },
});
```